# How does a speaker cable gague relate to its cross sectional area?

Tags: speakers

According to this [chart](https://www.rapidtables.com/calc/wire/wire-gauge-chart.html#chart), it seems that gauge and cross-sectional-area are inversely proportional (larger cross sectional means smaller gauge).

I am finding it hard to understand a statement in my speaker-manual:

> "Always use good quality speaker cable with 2.5mm minimum cross
> sectional area per conductor (79 strands)...For cable runs longer
> than 5m use a significantly heavier gauge cable."

The first sentence seems to recommend a wire that has **at least 2.5mm cross sectional** would mean wire with gauge 10 and lower?

The final sentence seems to recommend *heavier gauge* does that mean larger gauge?  Because that contradicts the first statement?  or does it mean lower gauge?

Comment: https://www.audioholics.com/frequent-questions/speaker-cable-gauge-distance -   https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffsb&q=SPEAKER+CABLE+guage+explained&ia=web - https://www.crutchfield.com/S-CgEHEBTS1aU/learn/learningcenter/home/speakers_wire.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heavier gauge means a lower number as your chart indicates.